# On what platforms will m_ofn members be valid?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, common-dialog

[According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43xtah3y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), some members (specifically the one I am interested in is the initial directory member lpstrInitialDir is not supported on Vista.

It is important for me to know if it is supported on 2008 and Windows7 - the docs are silent on that.  One can either assume since those are not mentioned that it will work, or since they are based on and newer than Vista that it will not work...

For bonus points, can anyone explain why in the world MS would remove such obviously needed behavior?  I am dumbfounded by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work in Windows7 32 bit...

So whatever happened over there in Redmond, it was fixed for Win7, but I'd love to know what the rationale was.

Given the behavior though, I don't think I will actually use it - it overrides the other desired behavior of the common dlg remembering where that app last saved a file.  Setting that member would put someone in a directory ALL the time.  I don't think that is good.  I only want to do it the first time (rather than in my docs the first time)